# So i'm trying to make a anti-afk program in VB.NET but it doesn't seem to be sending keys to the program?

Tags: vb.net

So i'm making a anti-afk program that every second will press the W key and for some reason it just doesn't work I tested it when I went to take a shower but the game still kicked me and I thought maybe i'm just not seeing it work

heres my code

```
        Dim num As Integer = 0
    Dim Win As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta").First
    AppActivate(Win.Id)
        SendKeys.Send("w")
    num = num + 1
        Label1.Text = "Keys Pressed : " & num.ToString()
```

Comment: Perhaps the game is too smart to be fooled by constantly receiving the same key repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the game also requires mouse move.